# Want to show out of stock associate product of group product

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

How can I show out of stock associate product of group product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associated grouped product collection is set from this file : `vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Link.php`

And collection function is : `getProductCollection()`

If you show out of stock associated group product then comment out this line : `$this->stockHelper->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);`

**Note** : do not edit core file, you have to overwrite this model file.